# How to increase the height of the Spinner's dropdown Listview (without using Custom ArrayAdapter)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm new to android and struggling in changing the height of the dropdown list's height of a spinner.
I'm using the following code to inflate my spinner.

code

```
 String[] fil_array = { "Starts with", "Contains" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> m_FilterAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            Mse_Customer.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fil_array);
    m_Filter.setAdapter(m_FilterAdap);
```

Please can anyone guide me how to achieve it.
Please have a look over the attached image for more clarity.
The second image  working correctly with the same type of code.Really confused why it is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of using a built-in layout crate your own with the height you want for each row

Comment: Without using any customArrayAdapter...It is possible? @tyczj

Comment: you dont need a custom array adapter to use a view you created, just pass in the resource id plus the data array and the resource fields

Answer (score 1):

don't use `android.R.layout` make your own custom layout

**layout_spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8.0dip"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="20.0sp" />
```

```
String[] fil_array = { "Starts with", "Contains" };
ArrayAdapter<String> m_FilterAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Mse_Customer.this, R.layout.layout_spinner_item, fil_array);
m_Filter.setAdapter(m_FilterAdap);
```

Comment: Its really helpful but the height of the the dropdown of the spinner is of the same size as the size of the text in it.Its not coming like the second image that i have attached. @ kishore jethva

Answer (score 0):

Create `custom_spinner_item.xml`

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />
```

Then in your code, replace:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> m_FilterAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mse_Customer.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fil_array);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> m_FilterAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mse_Customer.this, R.layout.custom_spinner_item, fil_array);
```

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned above...but the dropdown list of Spinner doesn't expand(as in second image).I tried by changing the margin top and bottom also...but nothing worked. @ Hussein El Feky

Answer (score 0):

create custom `drop_down_spinner_item` in xml and set:
`layout_height="wrap_content"` and `minHeight="40dp"`;